# HOW to remove duplicate JSON Objects from JSON Array

Tags: java, json

I have got the JSON as below

```
{
    "brands": [
        {
            "name": "ACC",
            "quantity": "0",
            "listedbrandID": 1,
            "status": "0"
        }
    ],
    "others": [
        {
            "name": "dd",
            "quantity": "55"

        },
        {
            "name": "dd",
            "quantity": "55"

        }

    ]
}
```

How can i remove the duplicates from `others` JSON array

i have tried as following

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


String json = "{
    "brands": [
        {
            "name": "ACC",
            "quantity": "0",
            "listedbrandID": 1,
            "status": "0"
        }
    ],
    "others": [
        {
            "name": "dd",
            "quantity": "55"

        },
        {
            "name": "dd",
            "quantity": "55"

        }

    ]
}
";



JSONObject json_obj = new JSONObject(json);

        JSONArray array = json_obj.getJSONArray("others");

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        System.out.println(array.length());

        for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
        {
            String name = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");

            String quantity = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("quantity");

            if(name!=null && !name.trim().equals(""))
            {
            map.put(name, quantity);
            }

        }
```

But no idea how to remove duplicate JSON other than which are present under Map only.

Comment: Consider using a `Set` rather than a `Map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an object representing your `Others`. It will have a `name` and `quantity` property and it will also override the `equals` method, wherein, two `Other` objects are considered to be equal if they have the same `name` and `quantity` properties.

Once you have that, iterate over your `JSON`, create a new `Other` object and place it in a `HashSet<Other>`. The `.equals` will ensure that the `HashSet` will contain unique items, as per your definition of unique.